# How to reduce the leakage current of a solid state relay?

Tags: power, relay, solid-state-relay, leakage-current

I have a zero-cross solid state relay (Crydom CKRD2420) that regulates the power output of a 2kW@240V heater using 10Hz PWM (e.g. [here](http://www.pamvotis.org/e-solutions/images/arduino/pwm.JPG) to illustrate). I need the power output of the heater to be under ~2W when OFF. However I measured the leakage current is 25mA RMS (2.5 times the 10mA garanteed in the datasheet, by the way...), which means that the power leakage is about 13W (the mains supply voltage reads 264V).

My first thought was a current divider, but the bleed resistor would reduce by a factor of 10 the available power, and reduce significantly the efficiency. I can't use a normal relay because of the lifetime required (I need at least 50-100M cycles of operation), and power MOSFETs would be tricky to implement. Are there any simple-ish fixes I have overlooked?

Comment: To me, the leakage current being out of spec says the SSR is damaged.

Comment: To me as well,  but I've got 4 of them and they all show the same leakage current - I don't see how they could all be damaged in the same way, especially given that they are used correctly...

Comment: Perhaps they are not?

Comment: BTW, Are you sure an AC SSR is the right thing for PWM? I would say you need a DC relay here... Also I am not quite sure how do you modulate AC with PWM. Can you provide some kind of schematic?

Comment: 10 Hz PWM on a heater is pretty odd, especially when fed from AC.  Typical cycle times for AC heater controls are on the order of 5 to 10 second periods, and the heater is enabled for a portion of that time slice.  Try using one SSR on each phase going to the heater.  Any circuitry around the SSR?

Comment: When the actual values do not match the promised ones, throw the things back at whomever gave them to you and get some that work to spec. Who knows what other surprises those hold.

Comment: As for your application, why does it matter at all? Just take that 13W into account when calculating the PWM signals that lead to your desired output.

Comment: I've updated my post with more info about the control. The circuit is actually litterally mains -> SSR -> heater, with the SSR being controlled by a temperature controller with 12V logic output. I only have a 240V neon indicator in parallel with the heater, which draws 1mA.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: it does matter because it decreases the temperature range; low temperatures close to ambient cannot be reached anymore when the heaters are wired but all OFF.

Comment: So where PWM is coming from in this scheme?

Comment: @MisterMystère: what is it that you are heating there that needs such a precision? 13W from a thing that I imagine being as big as a monitor is tiny compared to the ~100W of a human walking into the room and out of it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From the temperature controller, to the SSR. The duty cycle of the SSR determines the power output; if the duty cycle makes the pulse shorter than half a mains cycle, the controller adjusts the PWM frequency to 1Hz.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Because it's a specific application, very roughly said a black body under vacuum.

Comment: Do you have measurement equipment available which could tell you the phase of voltage and current? Maybe you are seeing some current which doesn't do anything (or is the heater actually getting warm)? Currently we have a figure of 13 VA not 13 W.

Comment: And how do you determine the RMS of a modulated AC? Weird things can happen when your PWM frequency is comparable to the mains frequency. And dividable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because it's not modulated when I measure the leakage current...

Comment: @MisterMystère Ah. Now that makes sense.

Comment: @MisterMystère: for such a high tech thing I think using IGBTs and DC with lots of amps is the better approach than some broken SSR.

Comment: @Arsenal: Good point, but not easily. Non intrusive current clamps are not accurate enough with 10 turns of wire,

Comment: @PlasmaHH: My opinion as well, though we can't go back to square one so I need to investigate how to fix the system, or perhaps increase the leakage power requirement...

Comment: @MisterMystère: use some relay in series that you PWM with <1Hz frequency when in the lower enegy requirements range?

Comment: > 1Hz you mean? Depending on how much time we spend at setpoints in the low end of the temperature range, using a relay to completely shut off the heaters only at these temperatures should be an acceptable option (talking about overlooking things...), thanks - I'll have to look at the lifetime though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'leakage' is no doubt coming from the internal snubber network. Perhaps they increased the capacitor value from when the datasheet was written.

The load resistance is R = 240^2/2000 = 29\$\Omega\$, so with 25mA leakage you'll have a power in the heater of 18mW (I^2R), which is not a problem. The '13W' you calculated is actually 13VA, almost all leading in phase and does *not* represent power either in the relay or the load.

So, I don't think you have a real problem. Your cycle time is a bit short- you may run into beating issues with the mains, but that's another issue.

Anyway, to answer your question, the easiest way to avoid the snubber would be to make your own SSR with a opto-triac and a snubberless triac (aka alternistor). But it's not necessary.

Comment: Of course! I stupidly multiplied the leakage current by the mains voltage, but if the leakage current is due to a snubber network and therefore not in phase, then it makes no sense to do so. If I had used RI² instead of UI in the first place I wouldn't have run into that trouble, but it's a good refresher of reactive power.

Comment: So it means the leakage current out of the SSR is leading in phase compared to the mains feed, and since a purely resistive load is connected, the voltage out of the SSR is also leading in phase, of amplitude Rx25mA=0.725VRMS, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. 0.7V only across the heater. You should be able to measure it directly.